# how to edit multiple values in sql table after pressing button in c#?

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I try to insert the sql code into c # so that I enter the values in the textbox and the given value is added to the table in the row and column after pressing

In sql it works fine, but in c # I probably have bad syntax.

```
TABLE
id nazov stav
1 múka   500
2 soľ    500
3 cukor  500
```

SQL code

```
UPDATE sklad_material SET stav = CASE nazov 
  WHEN 'múka' THEN sklad_material.stav + 100 
  WHEN 'soľ' THEN sklad_material.stav + 50 
  WHEN 'cukor' THEN sklad_material.stav + 100 
END 
WHERE nazov IN ('múka','soľ','cukor')
```

result

```
id nazov stav
1 múka   600
2 soľ    550
3 cukor  600
```

my attempt in c#

```
    private void add2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            string query = "UPDATE sklad_material SET stav = CASE nazov WHEN 'múka' THEN sklad_material.stav +'" + 100 + "'WHEN 'soľ' THEN sklad_material.stav +'" + solText.Text + "'WHEN 'cukor' THEN sklad_material.stav+" + textBox3.Text + "END WHERE nazov IN('múka','soľ','cukor')";    
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query, connection);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("pridané");
            connection.Close();
            populate();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

part of sql code in c#

```
    string query = "UPDATE sklad_material SET stav = CASE nazov
 WHEN 'múka' THEN sklad_material.stav +'" + 100 + 
"'WHEN 'soľ' THEN sklad_material.stav +'" + solText.Text + "'WHEN 'cukor' THEN sklad_material.stav+" + textBox3.Text + "END WHERE nazov IN('múka','soľ','cukor')";
```

It does not respond when the button is pressed
Can anyone please check my syntax in the code?

Comment: The c# Sql string looks like it's trying to add a numeric column values to strings. I doubt that is intended.

Comment: Look into `OracleCommand.Parameters` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oracleclient.oraclecommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_OracleClient_OracleCommand_Parameters

Comment: **Required reading: https://bobby-tables.com/** SQL injection is not just a problem of *security* but of *correctness*